# Динамическое добавление ViewPager. Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Есть `LinerLayout`, в него вбрасываются View(`TextView`, `Button` и так далее), по мимо них вбрасывается и `ViewPager` который работает слайдером и показывает картинки из сети.

Проблема в следующем: после того как я добавил он ставит какой-то не понятный размер(явно меньше картинки), что не дает отобразить содержимое.

Вот код

```
ImageSliderAdapter imageSliderAdapter = new ImageSliderAdapter(imagesUrl, App.getContext());

ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(App.getContext());
viewPager.setAdapter(imageSliderAdapter);
layout.addView(viewPager);
```

Разметка для ImageSliderAdapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgview_pager_silder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:clickable="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Как сделать так чтобы размер `imgview_pager_silder` подбирался в зависимости от размера экрана или изображения?

Comment: Попробуйте задать жестко высоту для ViewPager

Comment: Добавь layout weight .